# Coin toss related problem

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

What is the minimum number of times a fair coin needs to be tossed so that the probability of getting at least two heads is at least 0.96?

Is there any shortcut way to calculate this?

Comment: The probability of getting no heads and the probability of getting exactly one head should be relatively clean and short answers.  The probability of getting at least two heads being greater than or equal to $0.96$ will occur if and only if the probability of getting exactly zero or one head is less than or equal to $0.04$.  Beyond that, you can make a table of values and see where that first occurs.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of getting at least two heads is $1 - P_n(0) - P_n(1)$, where $P_n(k)$ denotes the probability of $k$ heads out of $n$ tosses, and can be calculated via $\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right) / 2^n$.  From this, you can easily try values of $n$ until you get $P_n(0) + P_n(1) < 0.04$.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the reason for the multiple edits.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll change it now.